# BDE to ADO conversion in DELPHI 2010

Tags: delphi, ado, bde

I am working on converting BDE to ADO for my company. I have run into an expression I can not figure out how to convert to ADO

Here is the BDE expression with all the ADO changes except for one....the part that is causing me issues is the

with Tquery.Create(nil) do at the beginning. Any ideas?

```
  with Tquery.Create(nil) do
        begin
            cmd := TStringList.Create;
            cmd.Add('select top 3 csnttext from casenotesint');
            cmd.Add('where csntcaseid = ''' + scasenum + ''' ');
            cmd.Add('and csntclmid = ''' + sclmnumber + ssplitcode + ''' ');
            cmd.Add('order by csntseqnum desc');
            rs := fConnection.Execute(cmd.Text);
            cmd.Free;

            while not Eof do
            begin
                SAPrintReport1.Tab(0.5);
                SAPrintReport1.Print(rs.Fields.Item('CsNtText').Value);
                SAPrintReport1.NewLine;
                rs.next;
            end;
            rs.Close;
        end;
        if cbxSpacer.checked then
        begin
            SAPrintReport1.NewLine;
            SAPrintReport1.NewLine;
            SAPrintReport1.NewLine;
        end;
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that BDE, ADO, and Delphi 2010 actually have nothing to do with your question? You're really just asking what "with Tquery.Create(nil) do" means, right?

Comment: Is that code correct? You're creating a TQuery and using its Eof property (due to the with), but then you're iterating over rs. Moreover I'd use parameters in the where clause, hope the input is checked and sanitized, or "fun" things could happen if your user is skilled enough (besides probably forcing a query hard parse every time).

Comment: Since your problem was in the end, not with the code you posted, you should amend your question or delete it to make StackOverflow a more useful place with less noise.

Comment: If you are using ADO, remove the TQuery.Create - TQuery is a BDE query. Search all your uses clauses for bde specific units (Mainly DBTables and bdeconst) and remove. This will ensure that you aren't acccidentally combining BDE and ADO.

Answer (score 2):

A `with` statement brings the given object's members into scope, so you can mention its fields, methods, and properties without having to qualify them with the name of the object they belong to. Please see [*With Statements*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#With_Statements) in the documentation.

One thing that's valid to put in a `with` statement is an object that was just newly created. That's the case here. The code creates a new `TQuery` object and immediately uses all its members implicitly. The reference to that object is not stored in any local variable, so there's no explicitly way to refer to it, but that doesn't bother the compiler. (It can bother humans, though, which is one of the reasons you'll see for people to discourage use of `with` in Delphi.)

Identifiers that don't belong to the given object are searched for in the next surrounding scope instead. It looks like the only identifier from `TQuery` being used in that `with` block is `Eof`, so the code you're converting is probably wrong anyway. It might be better to just figure out what the code was *supposed* to be doing, and then write new ADO code for that.

Answer (score 1):

You tried changing the TQuery to a TADOQuery, and then what happens?

Comment: I resolved the issue. The DB connection is opened on the form create, I was having an issue of redundancy

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should use try..finally..free..end; 
Otherwise, you're creating a query and never freeing it.
i.e. line 2 should be "try".

```
with Tquery.Create(nil) do 
try
  ..  
  ..  
finally
  free;
end;
```